# export 'ValidationProvider' (imported as 'ValidationProvider') was not found in 'vee-validate'

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm using vue 3 with vee-validate:

**package.json file**

```js
"vee-validate": "^4.7.3",
```

**Code**

```html
...
...
...
<ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ passes }">
  <form @submit.prevent="passes(onSubmit)">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <p class="text-medium-emphasis">Sign In to your account</p>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="input-group ">
        <ValidationProvider vid="email" name="email" v-slot="{ errors }">
          <input v-model="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" autocomplete="Email" class="form-control">
          <div class="error-message">{{ errors[0] }}</div>
        </ValidationProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-4">
      <div class="input-group ">
        <ValidationProvider vid="password" name="password" v-slot="{ errors }">
          <input v-model="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="form-control" type="password">
          <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
        </ValidationProvider>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary px-4">Sign in</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-link px-0" type="button"> Forgot password? </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</ValidationObserver>
...
...
...
<script>
  import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage, ValidationProvider, 
  ValidationObserver } from "vee-validate";
  export default {
      components: { Form, Field, ErrorMessage, ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver },
...
...
...
```

But has warning:

> export 'ValidationObserver' (imported as 'ValidationObserver') was not found in 'vee-validate' (possible exports: ErrorMessage, Field, FieldArray, FieldContextKey, Form, FormContextKey, IS_ABSENT, configure, defineRule, useField, useFieldArray, useFieldError, useFieldValue, useForm, useFormErrors, useFormValues, useIsFieldDirty, useIsFieldTouched, useIsFieldValid, useIsFormDirty, useIsFormTouched, useIsFormValid, useIsSubmitting, useResetForm, useSubmitCount, useSubmitForm, useValidateField, useValidateForm, validate)

[image]

And in console: [image]

Has anyone had the same situation as me?

Answer (score 0):

None of that stuff is in Vee-Validate version 4.7.3. You need to use an older version if you want ValidationObserver and ValidationProvider. Try this:

```
"vee-validate": "^3.1.0",
```